# How to get rid of Add All To Cart from Wishlist

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist, addtocart

Want to get rid of the Add All To Cart button from Wishlist as it's not particularly useful (it automatically adds 1 of every item even if I put 5 or 0 in quantity for one of the items). Plus it's supposed to keep the items in the wish list upon Adding All To Cart, which it mostly does but in some instances it'll take 1-3 items off the wishlist and keep the others.

Tried commenting out the public function allcartAction() in app/code/core/mage/Wishlist/Controller/Abstract.php but that made the wishlist not open at all.

Anyone have experience doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto

```
app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/template/wishlist/button
```

or

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/button
```

Find for this file `tocart.phtml` comment this lines

```
<?php if($this->getWishlist()->getItemsCount() && $this->getWishlist()->isSalable()): ?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add All to Cart') ?>" onclick="addAllWItemsToCart()" class="button btn-add"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add All to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
<?php endif;?>
```